# How does android do Password Validation?

Tags: android, device-admin

I have added a password policy with the following requirements for an android device.

- Minimum Password Length - 4
- Maximum failed password attempts - 3

Then I created a password with four characters.

Expected behaviour in this scenario is that the device wipes data (Factory Reset) after three failed attempts to log in.

This behaviour is correctly observed when I try to log in and fail three times with a password which has a `passwordLength >= 4`; but when the `passwordLenth < 4` The device doesn't wipe after three failed attempts.

Is this the intended behaviour of android?

Comment: show your works

Comment: It sounds like the right behaviour, because the password of length < 4, by the constraints can't be a real password and probably just is you missing a letter in the password

Comment: @J j Even when the password length is < 4, the device indicates it as a wrong password. But it does not get counted as a failed attempt. Do you have any idea where I can find the code this validation happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour of Android.
Since the minimum length of a password is set to 4, entries less than 4 characters will not be considered as threats since they are not registered as valid password entries.

But if the entry contains more than 4 characters, this will be considered as a valid password and processed because this can be a risk as user can enter different entries and try to crack the password.

So the company reset/ wipe data triggers only when a user enters 3 or more valid password entries.